# In the Messianic Age, will there be a period of time where people can repent for their mistaken worship of false religions?

Tags: avodah-zarah, messiah, messianic-redemption

**If someone is genuinely worshipping the Abrahamic God, even if in an incorrect way which they wholeheartedly believe to be correct, do they not get a chance to correct themselves when the Mashiach comes and clarifies everything?**

This is something that I wrestle with as I look at the world and see various people of faith. While Islam and Christianity are existing outside of the truth of Torah, they have faithful individuals who practice the worship of the Abrahamic God in a way they truly believe to be right.

- All three are waiting for the Mashiach.
- All three believe in sin and repentance for sin.
- All three believe in a Messianic Age.
- All three are worshiping the Abrahamic God (though Christians warped their definition of this).

This is especially true with Islam in that the Muslims live a lifestyle which mirrors certain aspects of Judaism. They have similar meat prep practices, Shia Muslims don't eat shellfish, there are modesty rules for men and women, worship services separate the sexes, they pray multiple times a day, etc. etc. etc.

There is obviously a long list of reasons why these groups do not agree on everything and why we believe some are more wrong than others. I'm not speaking to the nature of those issues.

If these groups are clear that they believe they are worshipping the Abrahamic God, if these groups believe they are doing so in a way they 100% believe to be correct (even if falsely) and they are living a life in hopes for the coming Messianic age.

**If this is all the case, does this mean there would be a period of time where the Mashiach will come and clarify the truth in the message and then give people a chance to change?**

Comment: I don't really follow. The Messiah will come and then people can do whatever they want.

Comment: If I'm understanding the OP, the question is implicitly wondering whether there will be an opportunity to receive reward for repentance right at the start of the messianic era before any form of "judgement." @DoubleAA

Comment: Christianity doesn't quite match the description you've given it. They are not exactly waiting for the Messianic Age, they do not have dietary prohibitions, modesty is very lax in many branches of Christianity, and the worship services are almost _always_ mixed, save for the Amish, Mennonites, and some more traditional Catholics. Christians also do not pray multiple times a day formally like Jews and Muslims.

Comment: Prayer at multiple times a day is a later rabbinic invention anyway, so you shouldn't read too much into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is yes. This is the primary subject of Rambam's Hilchot Melachim, 11:4 through the end of chapter 12.

Like it says:

> וִיתַקֵּן אֶת הָעוֹלָם כֻּלּוֹ לַעֲבֹד אֶת ה' בְּיַחַד שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר כִּי אָז אֶהְפֹּךְ אֶל עַמִּים שָׂפָה בְרוּרָה לִקְרֹא כֻלָּם בְּשֵׁם ה' וּלְעָבְדוֹ שְׁכֶם אֶחָד):

And as it continues in the censored portion:

> אבל מחשבות בורא עולם--אין כוח באדם להשיגם, כי לא דרכינו דרכיו ולא מחשבותינו מחשבותיו. **וכל הדברים האלו של ישוע הנוצרי, ושל זה הישמעאלי שעמד אחריו--אינן אלא ליישר דרך למלך המשיח, ולתקן את העולם כולו לעבוד את ה' ביחד: שנאמר "כי אז אהפוך אל עמים, שפה ברורה, לקרוא כולם בשם ה', ולעובדו שכם אחד" (ראה צפניה ג,ט).**
>   ח כיצד: כבר נתמלא העולם כולו מדברי המשיח, ומדברי התורה ומדברי המצוות, ופשטו דברים אלו באיים רחוקים, ובעמים רבים ערלי לב; והם נושאים ונותנים בדברים אלו, ובמצוות התורה--אלו אומרים מצוות אלו אמת היו, וכבר בטלו בזמן הזה, ולא היו נוהגות לדורות. ואלו אומרים דברים נסתרות יש בהם, ואינן כפשוטן, וכבר בא משיח, וגילה נסתריהם.
>   ט **וכשיעמוד המלך המשיח באמת, ויצליח וירום ויינשא--מיד הם כולן חוזרין ויודעים ששקר נחלו אבותיהם, ושנביאיהם ואבותיהם הטעום.**

Comment: Would be great if you could provide English translation)